# remove nested element using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

I am new to regex.  I want to only capture the text portion from `<firstpar>` or to remove all `<asmbly>` with all its children nodes and values.  Can anyone show me how to do that. The following is the snap shot of the xml fiel.  thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<firstpar>
    <thumbcred>Sample 1 thumbcred</thumbcred>
    <asmbly>
       <caption>
           <p><work ty="drawing">Two Fabulous Animals</work>Sample 1 <e> sample 1caption </e></p>
        </caption>
        <credit>Paul Miller/AP</credit>
        <asset id="126099" hgt="450" wdth="289" tmstp="24-OCT-08"
            bintype="2" filename="images/sample126099.jpg" source="eb" bighgt="1600"
            bigwdth="1029" bigfilename="botany003.jpg"
            bigdeployfullfilename="/eb-media/99/126099-050-CAD1EF0A.jpg"
        />

        <copyright>Copyright © 1994-2013 Encyclopædia Britannica,  Inc.</copyright>
    </asmbly>

Sample firstpar text <e>Sample e</e> just some
text <sub>sample sub </sub><e>sample e text again</e> more text with sup sub e. 

    </firstpar>
```

Comment: I'm no expert on the matter, but I think you may want an xml parser, not regex

Comment: Use an XML parsing library, **NOT** regex.  XML is a context-free language, not a regular language.

Comment: There are many good (and free) XML parsers available.  What language are you using so we can point you towards the right tool and how to use it?

Comment: I am trying to get the text portion of <firstpar> in c#.  Is there a good xml parsers that you can suggest?  Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, one of the known limitations of regex is that it does **not** handle nesting

You can and should use whatever XML parser is available in whatever language you're using.

---

If you have a very specifically formed piece of XML, and a very specific goal, than it is possible to use regex to perform some operations on it, but once you try to apply your regex to a non-specific piece of xml, it will be unable to handle it.

Comment: That first statement is a bit of a generalisation. Both PCRE's and .NET's regex flavor can very well handle nesting (and the OP happens to be using C#), and for some simple cases quite elegantly. It's more that XML is ridiculously complex, because of attribute values, XML comments, CDATA and whatnot which makes it near impossible to write a robust regex on XML.